# Basis for a Subspace over Complex Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U = \{(a, b, c, d, e)\in\mathbb{C}:6a=b,c+2d+3e=0\}$

Part of the question is proving that U is a subspace, which I have already done by checking the three criteria of a subspace. Now I must find a basis for U. I came up with the following:

$[a, 0,0,0,0], [0, 6a, 0,0,0], [0,0,c,0,0], [0,0,0,3c,0], [0,0,0,0,-2c]$

I am not sure if this is correct or not because the question mentions nothing about whether or not $a,b,c,d,e\not= 0$

Comment: The $a-e$ are just variable names, they are not constants. The set $U$ consists of 5-tuples of complex numbers that satisfy the two linear constraints. A basis will have concrete numbers.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you @copper.hat

Comment: Note that if you pick $a,d,e$ then there are formula for $b,c$. So you can pick $a,d,e$ arbitrarily and $b,c$ will follow.

Comment: So, for example, the point $(a,6a,2d+3e,d,e)$ is always in $U$ and for any point in $U$ you can find a,d,e$ such that it matches that point.

Comment: This suggests that the dimension is $3$ (because I can choose $a,d,e$ indepdendently). To find a basis, you could choose $a=1, d=0,e=0$ and get the 5 tuple associated with these numbers. Repeat with $a=0,d=1,e=0$ and then $a=0,d=0,e=1$. Convince yourself that this is a basis.

Answer (score 1):

As @copper.hat suggested above $(a, b, c, d, e)\in U, b=6a,c=-2d-3e$ therefore

$$ \Rightarrow (a, 6a, -2d-3e, d, e) = a\times(1,6,0,0,0)+d\times(0,0,-2,1,0)+e\times(0,0,-3,0,1)$$

Thus one basis is $\{(1,6,0,0,0),(0,0,-2,1,0),(0,0,-3,0,1) \}$, (any linear combination of these three with dimension $3$ is also a valid basis for $U$, the scalars are from $\mathbb{C}$ of course)

Comment: Hmmm, that's right, i'll correct it, thanks for heads up.